# AsyncTask has errors - beginner

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Eventually I am wanting this method to look up some values in a text document and return true of the username and password are present there. However I am having some problems with implementing the AsyncTask. I have tried to follow the guide at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html but have had no success.

The error I am getting at the return type on the doInBackground method is "The return type is incompatible with AsyncTask.doInBackground(String[])"

```
    private class AuthenticateUser extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>
    {
        String user;
        String pass;

        protected void onPreExecute(String uname, String passwd)
        {
            user = uname;
            pass = passwd;
        }

        protected boolean doInBackground(String... strings)
        {
            return true;
        }

        protected boolean onPostExecute(boolean v)
        {
            return v;
        }
    }
```

I know that this is not a good way to authenticate a user at all. I am just trying to figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to override `doInBackground` method of `AsyncTask`?

Comment: just put `Override` before `doInBackground` this will give u automatically default structure of `doInBackground` method according to params passed in `AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>`

Comment: try changing `protected boolean doInBackground(String... strings)` to `protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings)` using the class Boolean instead of the primitive boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem here is that AsyncTask Extensions are generic and need three types: `AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>` which may be Void or a class, but not primitive data types.

so what happens is you told the compiler that doInBackground returns a primitive boolean but it was expecting an instance of the class Boolean. and thus you get the "The return type is incompatible" error.

just change `protected boolean doInBackground(String... strings)` to `protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings)` and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Oren, that has sorted it. However, I have another error that i forgot to mention. 

I am getting AuthenticateUser cannot be resolved as a type when  I do:

new AuthenticateUser.execute("http://path/to/file.txt");

Comment: Do i heave to do this even if AuthentcateUser is a subclass?

Comment: `private class AuthenticateUser` the `private` part may have something to do with that. [this usage example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example) may help you. note the asynctask's class is private as it resides in the scope of another, public, class. you can follow that design or just make your `AuthenticateUser` class public (depending on your expected usage). side note: if an answer on Stack Overflow helped you, you should accept it so it can help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
 new AuthenticateUser().execute(username, password);
```

.

```
 private class AuthenticateUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>
    {
        String user;
        String pass;

        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings)
        {
            this.user = strings[0];
            this.pass = strings[1];

            //authen
            return true;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
        {
             //do stuff when successfully authenticated 
        }
    }
```